# SliceContourPlot3D not showing contours for small object

Tags: plotting

Suppose I am using `SliceContourPlot3D` to plot the contours of $x^2$ a sphere of radius $R$:

```
Module[{R, sphere},

 R = 1;
 sphere = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == R^2;

 SliceContourPlot3D[x^2, sphere, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]

 ]
```

If $R=1$ this looks like:

[image: Plot for R=1]

If I set $R=0.1$ however the contour lines disappear:
[image: Plot for R=0.1]

I can't find a way to get the contours to appear. Rescaling the function $x^2\rightarrow\frac{x^2}{R^2}$ doesn't do anything, neither does increasing the `PerformanceGoal`, number of `Contours`, or `PlotPoints`. How can I make the contours show up even for a small object?

Comment: Moreover, even the sphere becomes invisible if you will set R=0.001. The step of contours by default is big enough for your case. Try to add the `Contours->{0.001}`

Comment: add the options `Contours->Range[-.01,.01,.0005]`, `PlotPoints->100`, and `PlotRange->All`?

Comment: Thanks a lot Rom38 and kglr, manually setting the step size of the contours fixed it.

Comment: @chris, posted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the options `PlotRange->All`, `PlotPoints->100`, and `Contours-> Range[-.1,.1,.01]^2` gives

[image]